# Accelerometer Vs gyroscope - measuring torque

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, torque, gyroscopes

Torque can be measured with an accelerometer (tangential-acceleration):

t = F*r and F=m*a, so we get a from the accelerometer, giving:

t = m*a*r

Torque can also be measured with a gyroscope (angular-acceleration):

t = F*r

The relationship between tangential (a) to angular (omega) acceleration:

[OK gyroscope gives angular-velocity, so differentiate this once and you get angular-acceleration]

a = omega*r

Giving:

t = m*(omega*r)*r = m*r^2 * omega

or if we include the moment of inertia:

t = I*omega

Questions:
22222222
[1] Is the assessment correct, Torque can be measured with an accelerometer OR with a gyroscope?

[2] what are the pros and cons of either method?

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss tangent acceleration of a rigid body when a torque is applied

\begin{equation}
t = I \alpha = Fr = \frac{Ia}{r}
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration ($s^{-2}$), I the moment of inertia and $a$ the tangential acceleration. Viewing the force F as ma when applied to rigid bodies can lead to mystakes, my suggestion is always work with torque, angular momentum, ecc... (your assumption is correct if you are considering all bodies at a certain distance r from the point of rotation and contained in the same plane, but its not valid in a more general case)

Gyroscope can be used to meausure torque by meausirng the variation of the directions of its angular momentum (torque is needed to modify the value of angular momentum but also its direction). But this is problably the most uncomfortable way to measure torque, infact gyroscope are often used to point in a specific direction (for example gyroscope used in airplanes). The metod with the tangential acceleration is simpler and can work fine, but most of torque measures are done by using a calibrated spring.

Comment: Many thanks Lorenzo, and yes all bodies are at a certain distance r from the point of rotation. But what of the pros and cons of either method?

Comment: using a gyroscope basycally has no pros, it's simply not practical. Digital accelerometers could be used if the data needs to be transmitted/show on a screen and they can have some applications. The concept of an accelerometer in pretty simple and maybe easier to use/fabricate in some cases